# How to pass array of objects as value in Context Provider

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I want to send the array of objects in ContextProvider value attribute, so that i can use it in another component using useContext() hook. So that in the component i can destructure values from the array and map the array and display it on the browser.

Here is the ContextProvider file code:-

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, createContext } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const APIContext = createContext();

export const APIContextProvider = (props) => {
  const [orders, setOrders] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const res = await axios.get("/api/orders");
      setOrders(res.data);

      //res.data returns ARRAY OF OBJECTS

      console.log(res.data);
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <APIContext.Provider value={?}>{props.children}</APIContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you dont pass objects as `value={{objects}}` and then later access it as `const {objects} = useContext(APIContext)`

Comment: But when i do this and when i want to access it as const {objects} = useContext(APIContext) it breaks the app and shows error that "Cannot destructure property 'orders' of 'Object(...)(...)' as it is undefined."

Comment: Do you import context in component like this `import {APIContext} from ../YOUR_CONTEXT_PATH`  before declaring `const {objects} = useContext(APIContext)`? Provide more code where you importing your context and where you wrapping your components in context